# How to figure out this probably simple equation

Tags: percentages

So i am starting up a new bee pollination service which provides bee hives to local farmers.

I am just having trouble with this question.

So for each `Ha` 2 bee hives are required for pollination.

[equattion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs2QP.png)

So I'm trying to come up with a formula to calculate the percentage of pollination coverage per each Ha (1: 1ha, 2: 10Ha, 3: 100 Ha, 4: 800 Ha)

What formula should I use?

So per each hectare 2 bee hives are required and i am trying to figure out the pollination percentage of the bee hives i need for 10 hectares, 100 hectares and 800 hectares

Comment: So, you are a newbee in this domain ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes i am

Comment: Not sure to understand : do you stay with two hives even when you have 10 Ha ? In this case, the pollinisation percentage should drop from 100% to 20%, isn't it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, but i need a way to calculate it all. So if I have 40 hives and 1 Ha need 2, what is the percentage of "Pollination Coverage" (I now realise I didn't state this in the question)

Comment: If 1 Ha needs 2 hives for 100% coverage, then if you have $N$ hives and $H$ Ha the coverage percentage is $pct=50*N/H$. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two variables : $H$ = number of hives and $A$ = area (measured in ha).

Applying the basic rule of proportionnality, the general ideal formula is $H/A=2/1$ ; otherwise said, idealy, one should have $H/2A = 1$ ; but you desire a percentage, therefore the previous "ideal" formula is $H/2A\times 100$%.

But in reality, this  quantity $H/2A$ for example if you double the area without doubling the number of hives will become 50%, and so on, therefore constitute the multiplicator ( less than $1$ in general ?) of the ideal $100$%.

Conclusion : the final  formula should be $(H/2A) \ \times \ $ 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, much needed. Couldn't be more thankful!

Comment: I just see my solution coincides with the proposal of @Jeroen Boschma.